# Cannot test transition from DST

Tags: linux, date, time, timezone, dst

I am having issues trying to test transition from DST. This is my timezone:

```
cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Rome
```

while this is the output of `zdump -v -c 2019,2023 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome`:

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 31 00:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Mar 31 01:59:59 2019 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 31 01:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Mar 31 03:00:00 2019 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 27 00:59:59 2019 UT = Sun Oct 27 02:59:59 2019 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 27 01:00:00 2019 UT = Sun Oct 27 02:00:00 2019 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 29 00:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Mar 29 01:59:59 2020 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 29 01:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Mar 29 03:00:00 2020 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 25 00:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Oct 25 02:59:59 2020 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 25 01:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Oct 25 02:00:00 2020 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 28 00:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Mar 28 01:59:59 2021 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 28 01:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Mar 28 03:00:00 2021 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 31 00:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Oct 31 02:59:59 2021 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 31 01:00:00 2021 UT = Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 2021 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 27 00:59:59 2022 UT = Sun Mar 27 01:59:59 2022 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 27 01:00:00 2022 UT = Sun Mar 27 03:00:00 2022 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 30 00:59:59 2022 UT = Sun Oct 30 02:59:59 2022 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 30 01:00:00 2022 UT = Sun Oct 30 02:00:00 2022 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  9223372036854689407 = NULL
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome  9223372036854775807 = NULL
```

European Summer Time begins (clocks go forward) at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in March (28 March 2021), and ends (clocks go back) at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in October (31 October 2021).

I issued the following to test the transition to DST:

```
sudo date -s '2021-03-28 01:59:59'
Sun Mar 28 01:59:59 CET 2021
Sun Mar 28 03:00:00 CEST 2021
```

The time indeed moves forward by 1 hour at 2:00 CET (01:00 UTC) and the timezone switches from CET to CEST.

However, I get this trying to test the transition from DST:

```
sudo date -s '2021-10-31 01:59:59'
Sun Oct 31 01:59:59 CEST 2021
Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CEST 2021
```

Setting the time directly to 02:00 actually triggers a timezone change:

```
sudo date -s '2021-10-31 02:00:00'
Sun Oct 31 02:00:00 CET 2021
```

Why is it changing timezone when setting the time to 2:00 while it is not when setting it to 1:59:59? Shouldn't it transition from DST at 3:00:00 nonetheless?

Comment: `date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted` when issued without `sudo`. @KamilCuk

Comment: I need to change the date. I need it to test DST transitions.

Comment: Please show the output of `zdump -v -c 2019,2023 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome`? || When giving the date to date it "guesses" the input timezone. The guess is honestly almost arbitrary, it picks first timezone that matches. So it guesses that `date -s '2021-10-31 02:00:00'` is in CET. Could you try like `date -s '2021-10-31 02:59:00 CEST'` and see if it changes to `CET` at `3:00`?

Comment: Thanks,@KamilCuk, it does change from CEST to CET at 3:00!  I guess the problem was indeed the wrong timezone "guess".